# Air application - how to run two instances at one time

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [starting an Adobe AIR application multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217307/starting-an-adobe-air-application-multiple-times)

I'm trying to test my air application with a java server on my machine but in the flash builder program only one instance can be run at one time.
How can I run two instances so I can test two users connecting to the java server I have built?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every AIR application has a .xml file that defines application properties. This file contains a `<id />` tag that defines the application identifier, start one application go to this file edit `<id />` tag to a new name and start the application again.