# How to change ID in "application.xml" to run multiple instance of an AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I wants to run more than one instance of my Adobe Air Application, So to do this it needs to be change the **ID** in "**application.xml**" file of the application which is present in the folder META-INF of installation directory.
But i don't know how to change this ID at run-time.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this or any other process is there to solve this problem ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7935672/3623547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change ID at run-time. The only way to run several instances is to prepare several packages with different `appID` in app descriptor xml - so to have several app descriptors.